# CKEDITOR - How to enable hyphenation?

Tags: ckeditor

Is it possible to enable hyphenation in CKeditor?
I'm unable to find anything regarding this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on some articles [auto hyphenation](http://drublic.de/blog/css3-auto-hyphenation-for-text-elements/) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens) (also [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#search=hyphenation)). Then you'll find that this feature is available in some browsers only. Still you can add it to the editor using [CKEDITOR.addCss](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-addCss) if you really like.